# VBA Code - Selenium - scraping webpage with ng-binding

Tags: html, vba, selenium, head

Newbie here!

I assembled a code that tries to get the text that appears in the "head" element of the html page: 1.3253/1.3325 XRP/USD - GateHub Markets

The code does not generate any error, it simply outputs : total count = 1, but not the text I am trying to extract.

Ideas on how to adjust it, please??

This is the HTML of the page I am trying to scrape:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="landing" class="ng-scope">
<head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data- 
ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) 
{display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate- 
shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>

<!--
   _____       _       _    _       _
  / ____|     | |     | |  | |     | |
 | |  __  __ _| |_ ___| |__| |_   _| |__
 | | |_ |/ _` | __/ _ \  __  | | | | '_ \
 | |__| | (_| | ||  __/ |  | | |_| | |_) |
  \_____|\__,_|\__\___|_|  |_|\__,_|_.__/

 GateHub is a platform for the Internet of Value.

 -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <base href="/">
   <title ng-bind="pageTitle" class="ng-binding">1.3253/1.3325 XRP/USD - 
 GateHub Markets</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

This is the code that tries to extract the text within the  part

```
Option Explicit
Private cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub New1()

Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
Dim Results As Selenium.WebElements
Dim Result As Selenium.WebElement

Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
cd.Start
cd.get "https://gatehub.net/markets/XRP/USD+rhub8VRN55s94qWKDv6jmDy1pUykJzF3wq"

If Not cd.IsElementPresent(FindBy.Tag("title"), 3000) Then
cd.Quit
MsgBox ("Not found!")
Exit Sub
End If

Set Results = cd.FindElementsByTag("title")
Debug.Print "Total found =" & Results.Count

Dim n As Long
For n = 1 To Results.Count
Debug.Print Results(n).Text
Next
cd.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Other languages have `driver.title` but I'm not familar with VB... have you tried that? In your case probably `cd.Title`. It should return the title of the page as a string.

Comment: Also, please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. This includes HTML.

Comment: This time I'm agree with you @JeffC :)

Comment: What error appearing here, for what code line? Also, it is possible a `value` attribute of that element rather than text.

Comment: Thanks! I tried cd.title but it is not OK for VBA purposes. Apologies for the screenshot: anyway, I will copy below also the part of the page I am trying to extract. @Prophet: I tried with .value, instead of .text, and I get same output: Total found = 1, but no value of the price I am looking to extract.

Comment: Maybe you should add some delay there to let the page and this specific element completely loaded?

Comment: thanks! I have added a 10 sec waiting time, after opening the page: (Application. Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")), so that the page is fully loaded, but still do not get the text I am after.

Comment: I take it there is no error message?

Comment: exactly, no error message!

Comment: Anyone, please, suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the wrong attribute. This element has css styling setting it's display to none.

[image]

You need, for example, `innerHTML` or `textContent`:

```
d.FindElementByCss('title').Attribute('innerHTML')
d.FindElementByCss('title').Attribute('textContent')
```

[Note.textContent:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)

**Differences from innerText**

> Don't get confused by the differences between Node.textContent and
> HTMLElement.innerText. Although the names seem similar, there are
> important differences:
>
> 1. textContent gets the content of all elements, including  and elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable”
>    elements.
> 2. textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast,
>    innerText is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden”
>    elements.
> 3. Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the
>    value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed
>    styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should
>    be avoided when possible.)